# Why is the command `fg` sometimes not working?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, command

It happens sometimes that I cannot access a stopped job with the command `fg`. The problem is that it eventually work if I repeatedly try to. Therefore in the end, I never know why it behaved as it did.

This happened to me a few minutes ago. Note that I am using an alias for `fg`, which is defined in my `bashrc` as such:

```
alias mm="fg"
```

Here was the output to `jobs`:

```
[2]+  Stopped                 vim src/subroutines.F90  (wd: ~/Codes/MPIcode/currentVersion/slotJet/dme)
```

When entering `mm` (or `mm 2`), I stay on the command line and this is the output:

```
vim src/subroutines.F90 (wd: ~/Codes/MPIcode/currentVersion/slotJet/dme)

[2]+  Stopped                 vim src/subroutines.F90  (wd: ~/Codes/MPIcode/currentVersion/slotJet/dme)
(wd now: ~/Codes/MPIcode/cambridgeBurner/testingVersion)
```

Eventually, I got back to my jobs (after the ~10th time I entered the command `mm`).

**Question:**

What can be the source of that behavior? Next time this happens, what can I check for?

Comment: hmm, I occasionally also send a vi into background but fg always works immediately - how did your vim go background? Press Ctrl-z ?

Comment: @StefanHegny Yes, with Ctrl-Z

Comment: and the behaviour is the same if you use `mm` or `fg` ?

Comment: @StefanHegny Yes it was

Comment: What is your environment?. Seems like cygwin on a terminal that do not refresh correctly. After `fg` you can press ctrl+l to redraw screen. And who writes that (wd:) (wd now:) part

Comment: @albfan What do you mean by environment? and about the (wd:), I just copy pasted the output I was getting after I enter the command.

Comment: I mean Operative system, terminal program, shell, and system variables. On linux it can be Ubuntu, gnome-terminal, bash, $TERM=xterm. on windows can be Windows 7, ConEmu, powershell, %TERM%=dumb. I think all was redraw problems. After comeback to foreground, vi didn't know it has to rewrite screen. Knowing environment can help to understand problem